# Android tests not recognizing Android classes

Tags: android, junit

I'm new to Android development, I'm trying to setup some unit tests for the first time. I'm having a weird issue. JUnit imports like org.junit.Test work fine, standard Android class imports like android.content.Context work fine, but attempting to import something like androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunnerfails, with the import just not being recognized.

I've been going through my build.gradle trying to figure things out, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. It's not just Android Studio, if I run gradle test I see the same errors.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.craigmiller160.cardgamescores"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

ext {
    baseResDir = 'src/main/res'
    baseLayoutsDir = "$baseResDir/layouts"
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = [
                    baseResDir,
                    "$baseLayoutsDir/common",
                    "$baseLayoutsDir/gameTypeList",
                    "$baseLayoutsDir/rummy500",
                    "$baseLayoutsDir/phase10"
            ]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def daggerVersion = "2.37"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable-jvm:0.3.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
}
```

### Edit

Here are more details. This is the test file in question:

```
import org.junit.Test
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4 // This is line 4
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) // This is line 7
class SqlPlayerRepositoryTest {
    // Stubbed out tests
}
```

And here are the gradle errors I get:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugUnitTestKotlin FAILED
e: /home/craig/Development/Applications/CardGameScores/app/src/test/java/io/craigmiller160/cardgamescores/persist/repository/sqlite/SqlPlayerRepositoryTest.kt: (4, 17): Unresolved reference: test
e: /home/craig/Development/Applications/CardGameScores/app/src/test/java/io/craigmiller160/cardgamescores/persist/repository/sqlite/SqlPlayerRepositoryTest.kt: (7, 10): Unresolved reference: AndroidJUnit4
e: /home/craig/Development/Applications/CardGameScores/app/src/test/java/io/craigmiller160/cardgamescores/persist/repository/sqlite/SqlPlayerRepositoryTest.kt: (7, 10): An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant
```

Comment: Is it possible to give more detail about the problem? About the line that you have a problem or something that shows the problem better. Or if you have an error message, please add it to the description too.

Comment: Just made the edits

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Android docs confused me on testing, so I'll explain it here.

Android has two separate testing directories. The standard "test" directory that is familiar to Java/Kotlin devs, and the "androidTest" directory. The classes I am trying to use are all loaded in gradle using the androidTestImplementation statement, which means that they are only available in the androidTest directory.

While it is possible to make them testImplementations so that they work in the test directory, there is extra setup that goes into testImplementations. I don't fully understand it, but it appears to require an AVD setup to generate a context behind the scenes. This makes these kind of tests clearly more expensive to perform, but also more robust at the same time.

Glad to have this figured out.